# Flush cache for memory allocated by kmalloc

Tags: linux-kernel

I allocate memory using kmalloc in my driver and I passed this address to my HW
register to write to.  My question is when the HW done writing (my
driver get notified by an interrupt), how can I flush the cache so
that my driver can see what has been written by the HW?

Thank you.

Comment: May be this will help https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt

Answer (score 0):

When you are using streaming DMA mapping, the `dma_map_`* and `dma_unmap_`* functions take care of flushing caches, if needed.

If you need to use the same streaming DMA region multiple times and touch the data in between the DMA transfers, you can use the `dma_sync_`* functions.

Read [Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) for details.